# Remove xticks but keep xticklabels in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a plot in MATLAB from which I would like to remove the `xtick`s but keep the `xticklabel`s. If I just remove the `xtick` like so:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', []);
```

...then the labels also disappear. Is there a way to keep the labels, without having to manually recreate them with text boxes? I thought about trying to make the length of the `xtick`s zero, but [this answer](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/17044) suggests that `xtick` properties cannot be independently controlled.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try modifying the `TickLength` property:

```
set(gca, 'Ticklength', [0 0])
```