# How to pass Imagesc frame into Matlab imwrite and imread?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I take a gray-colormap frame of imagesc, try to `gray2ind`-`ind2rgb` for `imwrite` and then read it again by `imread` but I get the error which indicates that the dimensions do not match.

```
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Error in ind2rgb (line 34)
  rout(:,:,1) = r;

Error in test_imagesc_output_imwrite (line 14)
Crgb = ind2rgb(Cind, parula(256)); % https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968435/54964
```

Code where I am uncertain how to pass `1-gray(1024)` colormap details to `gray2ind` correctly; I think `gray2ind(I,256)` can lose pieces of information; also, `ind2rgb(Cind, parula(256)` is not correct but I cannot use there `1-gray(1024)` directly

```
clear all; close all; clc; 
x = [5 8];
y = [3 6];
C = [0 2 4 6; 8 10 12 14; 16 18 20 22];
f=figure; 
hax=axes(f); 
imagesc(hax, x,y,C) % I could not use here I=imagesc and then I.CData for some reason
colormap(hax, 1-gray(1024)); 
I=getframe(hax); 
I=I.cdata; 
assert(isa(I, 'uint8'), sprintf('I is not uint8 but %s', class(I)));
Cind = gray2ind(I, 256); 
% TODO here something
Crgb = ind2rgb(Cind, parula(256)); % https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968435/54964
imwrite(Crgb, '/home/masi/Images/1.png');

I=imread('/home/masi/Images/1.png'); 
assert(isa(I, 'uint8'), sprintf('I is not uint8 but %s', class(I)));
f2=figure;
hax=axes(f2); 
imagesc(hax2, I);
```

Fig. 1 Imagsc gray image which is `getframe` and tried to be stored by `imwrite` and read by `imread`

[image]

Matlab: 2016a
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Motivation: I am getting artefact in `export_fig` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39963795/54964) but also now observing phase shifts from `1-gray` to `gray` when saving `[I,alpha]=export_fig(...)` so trying with Matlab `imwrite`/`imread`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variabel `I` is RGB data (`M x N x 3`)  so when you pass it to `gray2ind` you are getting back an `M x N x 3` matrix of indices. `ind2rgb` accepts a 2D array of indices and *not* the 3D array that you're passing it.

I'm not quite sure what you expect, but you could first convert `I` to a true grayscale image first using `rgb2gray`

```
I = getframe(hax);
I = rgb2gray(I.cdata);
Cind = gray2ind(I, 256);
Crgb = ind2rgb(Cind, parula(256));
```

Or you could skip *all of this* and just set the colormap of your figure to `parula` and pass `I.cdata` directly to `imwrite`

```
imagesc(C, 'Parent', hax);

% Use an inverted parula colormap which seems to be what you're trying to do
colormap(flipud(parula(256)));
I = getframe(hax);

imwrite(I.cdata, '1.png')
```

Comment: @Masi you don't need either of those if you just want gray...just use `I` directly.

Comment: @Masi I'm a little confused what you mean. Are you saying that if you hide the axes it still shows up when using `getframe`?