# How to linkdata images on Matlab polaraxes?

Tags: matlab, debian, matlab-figure, polar-coordinates

I am trying to `linkdata` images on polaraxes, which is nicely described for `plot`/`area`/... as cartesian in `linkdata` documentation [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkdata.html). 
Code where the first segment makes two images with cuts based on alpha values. 
The second segment loops and draws those images on polaraxes. 
After the first iteration, `linkdata on` activates but I get the notification which does not offer `Fix it` option as normally in Fig. 1. 
I think the bug is in the fact that I cannot explicitly define the datasource of `linkdata` as images, see Attempt 1. 
Code

```
close all; clear all; clc;
af = figure('Name', 'Do Not Touch');
%% Data generation
f = figure;
hax = axes(f);
rgb = 'peppers.png';
% http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/18/image-overlay-using-transparency/
rgb = imread('peppers.png');
I = rgb2gray(rgb);
h = imagesc(I, 'Parent', hax);
[M,N] = size(I);
block_size = 50;
P = ceil(M / block_size);
Q = ceil(N / block_size);
alpha_data = checkerboard(block_size, P, Q) > 0;
alpha_data = alpha_data(1:M, 1:N);
set(h, 'AlphaData', alpha_data.^2);
zeroFigureDecorations(hax); 
images{1} = getframe(hax);

[M,N] = size(I);
block_size = 50*2;
P = ceil(M / block_size);
Q = ceil(N / block_size);
alpha_data = checkerboard(block_size, P, Q) > 0;
alpha_data = alpha_data(1:M, 1:N);
set(h, 'AlphaData', alpha_data.^2);
images{2} = getframe(hax);

close all;
clearvars -except images;     

%% Polar
% http://stackoverflow.com/a/40063951/54964
fp=figure('Name', 'Test', ...
    'Position',[200 200 851 404],'Resize','off'); % only half circle on polaraxes although warp can do eclipses
ThetaTicks = 0*pi:pi/10:1*pi;
pax = polaraxes( 'ThetaAxisUnits', 'radians', ...
    'ThetaLim',[min(ThetaTicks) max(ThetaTicks)],...
    'Color','none',...
    'GridAlpha',1,...
    'GridColor',[1 1 1],...
    'ThetaTick', ThetaTicks, ...
    'ThetaDir', 'counterclockwise', ...
    'Parent', fp);
imax = axes('Parent', fp, 'Visible', 'off');
zeroFigureDecorations(imax); 

for image=images
    h = imagesc(image{1}.cdata, 'Parent', imax); 

    zeroFigureDecorations(imax); 

    linkdata on; 

    angleRadians=-pi;
    I = getframe(pax);
    I = I.cdata;
    [x, y, z]=makePolar(I, angleRadians);
    imax.Children = warp(x, y, z, I);
    set(imax,'view',[-180 -90],'Visible','off');
    axis(imax,'tight')
    pause(0.5);
end

function zeroFigureDecorations(ax)
axis(ax, 'tight');
set(ax, 'yTickLabel', []);
set(ax, 'xTickLabel', []);
set(ax, 'Ticklength', [0 0]); % http://stackoverflow.com/a/15529630/54964
colormap(ax, gray(1024));
box(ax, 'off');
axis(ax, 'off');
end
```

Fig. 1 Single images are correct on polaraxes, here after the second iteration; the top bar shows the failed `linkdata` attempt and does not offer `Fix it` option like normally

[image]

### Attempt 1

To explicitly set `guihandles` and `datasources` but no effect probably because no explicit application of `linkdata` on images as datasource

```
...
myhandles = guihandles(fp); 
for image=images
    h = imagesc(image{1}.cdata, 'Parent', imax); 
    myhandles.output = h; 
    myhandles.yData = []; 
    myhandles.xData = []; 
    set(get(myhandles.xData, 'Children'), 'XDataSource', myhandles.xData);  
    set(get(myhandles.yData, 'Children'), 'YDataSource', myhandles.yData);  
    ...
end
```

### MathWorks' contact

MATLAB feedback forum answer

> The short answer is that polaraxes does support data linking, however
>   it looks like you are using warp, which is creating a type of surface
>   object that does not support data linking.  There are workarounds for
>   this, for example you might be able to modify the warp.m file to use
>   surf rather than surface.

I am working with the service request about the topic.

MATLAB: 2016b
OS: Debian 8.5
MathWorks Service Request: #02229120

Comment: @AnderBiguri Please, see the docs of linkdata. Polar presentation should wotk similarly as cartesian.

Comment: IF you post also alternative code for previous versions of MATLAB, i migth be able to help, but I can not run that code because of versions issues.

Comment: @AnderBiguri What is your MATLAB version?

Comment: 2014b. Basically anything before 2016b does not accept the way you handle axes and pass them to functions (e,g, `Parent, hax`)

Comment: Not saying you shoudl change it, just that I may be able to help if you do, no pressure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB support answer is the current one, because there is no development plan about the fix

> The short answer is that polaraxes does support data linking, however it looks like you are using warp, which is creating a type of surface object that does not support data linking. There are workarounds for this, for example you might be able to modify the warp.m file to use surf rather than surface.