# How to do imagesc and axis off at the same time in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, graphics, debian, matlab-figure

I want to prevent `imagesc` drawing any decorations (box, axis, ...) in the first place because of bugs existing in Matlab graphics, which I see as artefacts mostly around textual elements. 
Zeroing all graphics before and after `imagesc` is not enough because artefacts etc textual "flopping" occurs when `imagesc` is just called. 
Pseudocode wanted

```
imagesc(x,y,C, 'axis', 'tight', 'axis', 'off', ...)
```

The point of the thread is **not** about how you reproduce those artefacts, but how you prevent them. 
The following is for the attempt to describe how you get the bug, but it is not the point of this thread.

### Pseudocode for minimum code

Steps to reproduce the artefacts

1. Plot PolarPlot or anything that has textual.
2. Plot a Parent plot on top of it such that the axis passes through any textual element.

Code which you need to connect with crossing textual elements with axis to reproduce Fig. 1

```
f = figure; 
hax = axes(f); 

zeroFigureDecorations(hax); 
imagesc(x,y,C, 'Parent', hax)
zeroFigureDecorations(hax); 

function zeroFigureDecorations(ax)
axis(ax, 'tight');
set(ax, 'yTickLabel', []);
set(ax, 'xTickLabel', []);
set(ax, 'Ticklength', [0 0]); % http://stackoverflow.com/a/15529630/54964
colormap(ax, gray(1024));
box(ax, 'off');
axis(ax, 'off');
end
```

Fig. 1 Example with similar case where calling `imagesc` creates the outer axis causing textual "flopping"

[image]

MATLAB: 2016b
OS: Debian 8.5
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Graphics: Intel

Comment: No. It is a property of the `axes` *not* the image object produced by `imagesc` therefore `imagesc` is going to ignore all of those parameters.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just do `imagesc(x, y, C); axis off;` I don't understand this textual "flopping" you're speaking of.

Comment: @rayryeng I think he's referring to the fact that turning `axis off` prior to calling `imagesc` is undone by `imagesc`

Comment: Why do they need to be run together? This better not be another XY problem.

Comment: @Masi If you're having issues please post a [mcve] which actually *demonstrates* the issue. There should be no issue with calling them one after another

Comment: @Masi Can you at least show a screenshot of the artifacts?

Comment: @Masi The code you have posted doesn't produce an image which looks anything like the image you have posted.

Comment: @Suever I added the steps to reproduce the artefact in the body because I cannot share directly the code yet. The bug is probably related to my reported bug to MathWorks with Intel graphics about missing hovering tooltips. - - The main point of this thread is not how you reproduce the bug but how you turn off the axis at the same time when doing `imagesc`.

Comment: @rayryeng We can ask also: Why Matlab inserts `axis on` by default in `imagesc` without giving the user permission to avoid it in the first place. - - So why is there XY problem in the first place?

Comment: @Masi we already stated that it can't be done and there is no reason why calling it immediately after is any different. We need you to reproduce it to see what the issue is

Comment: @Suever I created a Service ticket with MathWorks about this. I reproduce it when I can with a minimum example.

Comment: @Masi In the example above, it looks like your axes is still visible so maybe that's part of the issue?

Comment: When I run your code with some random data for `C` I get an image with no axis.

Comment: @EBH Do you mean this line `imagesc(x,y,C, 'axis', 'tight', 'axis', 'off', ...)`? - - It should not be possible. - - The second code will have the feature but it does the axis off after imagesc, not at the same time. Which is your Matlab version?

Comment: I use 2016a. You mean you want to achieve this without the `zeroFigureDecorations` function?

Comment: @EBH Yes, because drawing the axis cause the artefact.

Comment: and why `hax.Visible = 'off';` after the `imagesc(x,y,C, 'Parent', hax)` is not good? or just `imagesc(x,y,C); ax = gca; ax.Visible = 'off';`? is it causing the same problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not possible to do `imagesc` and `axis off` at the same time. 
However, you can modify the imagesc code to achieve this but you will not get MathWorks support for the modified version. 
To avoid the graphical artifacts, try different figure renderers: *painters*, *opengl*, ... 
You can also try the startup flag `-softwareopengl`.