# How to detect peaks on gray background with Matlab FastPeakFind?

Tags: matlab, detection

I am testing the validity of the FileExchange project [`FindPeaksFast`](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37388-fast-2d-peak-finder) with different linewidths and backgrounds. 
Test 1 is successful and the tool detects all peaks from 1px to 10 px. 
However, Test 2 fails when testing to find peaks on the frame of an object plot i.e. an object (plot) on gray background. 
The tool works well on white background. 
Code

```
close all; clear all; clc;

f = figure; 
hax = axes(f); 
% Comment this out for Test 2
%zeroFigureDecorations(hax); 

af = figure('Name', 'Do Not Touch');

x = rand(1,100);
y = rand(1,100);
linewidth=1; 
plot(hax, x,y, 'LineWidth', linewidth); 

I = getframe(hax); 
I = I.cdata; 

% https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37388-fast-2d-peak-finder
p=FastPeakFind(I);
% Input: 344x435x3 uint8

hold(hax, 'on'); 
plot(hax, p(1:2:end),p(2:2:end),'r+')
hold(hax, 'off'); 

function zeroFigureDecorations(ax)
axis(ax, 'tight');
set(ax, 'yTickLabel', []);
set(ax, 'xTickLabel', []);
set(ax, 'Ticklength', [0 0]); % http://stackoverflow.com/a/15529630/54964
colormap(ax, 1-gray(1024));
box(ax, 'off');
axis(ax, 'off');
end
```

Outputs in the following, and Fig. 1 shows that the function can detect something on lines when the background is white but not on correct locations.

> ```
> Linewidth Output  
> 10        166x1 double 
> 1         844x1 double 
>
> Table: full axis decoration in Test 1
>
> Linewidth Output
> 10        []
> 1         [] 
>
> Table: no axis decorations, after zeroFigureDecorations(hax) in Test 2
> ```

Fig. 1 line as input (See Bla's answer) and its output, 
Fig. 2 Output is wrong in Section 2, 
Fig. 3 One more example that you cannot apply to function to simple curves, 
Fig. 4 Section 3 Output is wrong, since not known how to apply the function on spectrograms

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### 2 Test with bla's example data

```
f0 = figure; 
hax0 = axes(f0); 
d=uint16(conv2(reshape(single( 2^14*(rand(1,128*128)>0.9995) ),[128 128]) ,fspecial('gaussian', 10,2),'same')+2^4*rand(128)); 
imagesc(d, 'Parent', hax0);

I = getframe(hax0); 
I = I.cdata; 
p=FastPeakFind(I);
hold(hax0, 'on'); 
plot(hax0, p(1:2:end),p(2:2:end),'r+')
hold(hax0, 'off');
```

Output is wrong in Fig. 2

### 3 Testing with spectrograms

```
f3 = figure; 
hax3 = axes(f3); 
N = 1024*10;
n = 0:N-1;

w0 = 2*pi/5;
x = sin(w0*n)+10*sin(2*w0*n);

s = spectrogram(x);
spectrogram(x,'yaxis')

p=FastPeakFind(s);
hold  on; 
plot(p(1:2:end),p(2:2:end),'r+')
```

Matlab: 2016b
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: you are not feeding the function with peaks. do `imagesc(I)` and see if you get peaks, I dont.

Comment: You are probably down voted because the question is not phrased well, you example is not a *minimal* working example as it requires the users to download the function from the FEX, it has a lot of unneeded stuff (the function at the end, most of the beginning and this makes it also not compatible with previous matlab versions so it doesn't work for many people)  and you don't understand how to use it in a basic way, that is, the function assumes sparse "real" peaks not single dots, and you feed it with some  lines.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by multifocal. peaks are distributions that have a distinct single maximum value.

Comment: the many lines intersection doesnt make it a peak, the intensity of that point is 1 like all other points in a line. You are not adding the lines.

Comment: your doing it wrong again. use `FastPeakFind(d)` your code makes no sense.

Comment: that's the problem in your code, you should be using `FastPeakFind(d)` becuase `d` is the array of peaks. `I` on the other hand is a screen shot of an RGB image. This is bad coding that I dont understand why you insist on doing. For example in the blue part of `I` , i.e. `I(:,:,3)` the peaks are minima instead of maxima etc. Use the actual "data" not a color screen grab of it that has some colormap that can change your results.

Comment: you can also see that `I` has a different size than `d`, while `d` in the example is 128x128 array, `I` is   343x434x3, so you are not analyzing the array you want...

Comment: last, again if you look at `I` just after peak-finding using `imagesc(I)` you'll get an "empty" figure (all maximum intensity, I dont know why)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the function correctly.

your code is this (verbatim):

```
f = figure; 
hax = axes(f); 
af = figure('Name', 'Do Not Touch');

x = rand(1,100);
y = rand(1,100);
linewidth=1; 
plot(hax, x,y, 'LineWidth', linewidth); 

I = getframe(hax); 
I = I.cdata;
```

The matrix `I` is not a matrix that contain peaks like the function is intended to have. This is how it looks like:

```
imagesc(I);
```

[image]

Even if all you had were single pixels, that is not what the function is supposed to have, as it is said that the peaks point spread function needs to be larger than some # of pixels, and that they are assumed to be sparse. The function has a demonstration on a sample image that works fine.

Also , it's completely unclear what you even mean by peaks here.

EDIT:

Here's an example of how to use the function. First let's select random positions where we "create" the peaks:

```
I=rand(200)>0.9995;
```

This makes a binary matrix with only the points larger than 0.9995 selected (or having value 1). At each step you can `imagesc(I)` to see how `I` looks.

In real life, a camera will have some intensity in these points so we write:

```
I=I*100;
```

This is important as the peak by dentition needs to be a maximum value in its neighborhood. In real life, peaks are mostly not single pixels, they have some "width" or spread (this is also what the function says it deals with):

```
I=conv2(I,fspecial('gaussian',10,2),'same');
```

here, this spread is done by a "point-spread function" of a guassian of some width.

Lets add some 30% noise (note that after the last step the maximum value of the peaks is no longer 100, because it is spread to other pixels as well):

```
I=I+0.3*max(I(:))*rand(size(I));
```

Let's find peaks

```
 p=FastPeakFind(I);
```

See how it did:

```
subplot(1,2,1);imagesc(I); 

subplot(1,2,2);imagesc(I); hold on
plot(p(1:2:end),p(2:2:end),'r+')
```

[image]

In the function code, the example is doing what I wrote here in a single line. Note that there is an `edg` parameter, as this will not work on peaks on the edges of the image. This cab be solved by padding the image with zeros I think...

Comment: I actually dont understand what you are talking about, grey background?! I see a bunch of lines here, where are those peaks that you look at?

Comment: but you use `p=FastPeakFind(I);` so `I` is the input the function sees.

Comment: do you really dont understand that lines are not peaks?

Comment: I copied it from the function itself.

Comment: `d=uint16(conv2(reshape(single( 2^14*(rand(1,128*128)>0.9995) ),[128 128]) ,fspecial('gaussian', 10,2),'same')+2^4*rand(128));
    imagesc(d);`

Comment: I dont know what you need really. looking at the comments to this function it is working great as long as you flatten the background. what image do yo need it to detect peaks at? why dont you send it to the person that wrote that function, there's an email mentioned there in line 55

Comment: also peaks are not high density areas. peaks are areas with a single maximum value. do you understand the difference?

Comment: in other words, all the intensity values of your lines are equal (and 1), the fact that they intersect doesnt increase their intensity

Comment: First `s` is not an image, since it has complex value data, and the function is not suppose to deal with that. Second, according to the image your matrix `s` has no 2D peaks that I can see with my eyes, just two lines so I don't understand what or why you even consider there are peaks here. Also the dimension of `s` is almost 1D, the function is 2D peak finder, not 1D one so it just unbelievable you are trying to  look for 1D peaks with a 2D finder. etc etc...

Comment: This is the last time I'll reply here. The level of your question is not appropriate to SO, and you should email the author of the function with your questions. But seriously are you even thinking before you ask these questions?